# Can $x+y=14$ and $xy=49 $ be solved algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By inspection it is obvious that the values of $x$ and $y$ are $7$, but I can't see how to solve it algebraically.

I thought that it could be solved as a system of equations, and substitute the value $x$ of the first equation into the second equation, but it comes up with some inconsistent answers.

I realised these expressions are not linear equations, therefore the substitution method is probably not going to work...

Can $x$ and $y$ be solved using the substitution method or any other algebraic method?

Comment: You should think about the substitution mehod. How does it work and when can it be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Viete formula $ x+y=14=-b/a\Rightarrow b/a=-14 $ and $xy=49=c/a $ follow that $x$ and $y$ are the roots of quadratic equation
$$aX^2+bX+c=0$$
$$X^2+(b/a)X+c/a=0$$
$$X^2-14X+49=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$x = 14-y \implies (14-y)y = 49 \implies 14y-y^2 = 49 \implies y^2-14y + 49 = 0\implies (y-7)^2 = 0 \implies y$ = ..?

Comment: +1 This is the standard method to solve this and similar problems. It does not need this very special property of the system of equation that allows the application of Vieta's theorem that the other answer use.

Answer (score 0):

We know that given for any two numbers $a$ and $b$, the values of $a+b$ and $ab$, we can use the identity $$(a-b)^2 = (a+b)^2-4ab$$ A direct application of this identity for $a+b=14$ and $ab=49$ and solving the two equations $$a+b=14$$ and $$a-b=0$$ would give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sum $s$ and the product $p$ of two numbers $x$ and $y$ then we can find  $x$ and $y$ by [solving the quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation) (with respect to $z$),
$$(z-x)(z-y)=z^2-sz+p=0.$$
Hence $x$ and $y$ are given by the formula
$$\frac{s\pm\sqrt{s^2-4p}}{2}.$$
In your case,
$$\frac{14\pm\sqrt{14^2-4\cdot 49}}{2}$$
and we obtain that $x=y=7$.